# WheelCommand takes at least 3 arguments, but only 2 are given

Tags: python, pip, python-wheel

I am trying to use the following nice automation to package my PySpark code to run it with spark-submit afterwards:

https://bytes.grubhub.com/managing-dependencies-and-artifacts-in-pyspark-7641aa89ddb7

https://github.com/alekseyig/spark-submit-deps

Since my version of pip is probably higher than the author's, I needed to do the following changes to setup.py:

`from pip.commands import WheelCommand` => `from pip._internal.commands.wheel import WheelCommand`

`from pip.req import parse_requirements` => `from pip._internal.req import parse_requirements`

But sadly, after that, if I try to run `python setup.py bdist_spark`, it returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "setup.py", line 116, in <module>
 "bdist_spark": BdistSpark
 File "<conda_env>\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
 return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
 File "<conda_env>\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
 dist.run_commands()
 File "<conda_env>\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
 self.run_command(cmd)
 File "<conda_env>\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
 cmd_obj.run()
 File "setup.py", line 43, in run
 wheel_command = WheelCommand(isolated=False)
 File "<conda_env>\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\wheel.py", line 52, in __init__
 super(WheelCommand, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

I have tried to fix it unsuccessfully, I can't find anything that helps me on SWF or pip documentation/code.

Could you please give it a look?

Comment: I would recommend against using _pip_'s code as a library, because this use case is not intended nor supported by the maintainers (see [this section of _pip_'s documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program)). This is why you most likely will not find any good documentation to fix this code. This code sample from _grubhub_ for _pyspark_ that you are trying to follow is poor advice in my opinion.

Comment: One workaround would be to replace wheel_command with os.system command to download the wheel files.
```os.system("pip wheel -r requirements.txt -w "+self.wheel_dir)```

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same exact Situation ( my version of Python 3.7). But I made progress and was able to do spark submit with 2 zip files(1 for dependencies and the actual code). Not Sure if this is the right way. build here is build from uranium. Below is the code how i put all dependent libs in to dist folder then zipped it after wards in gradle tasks

```
from uranium import current_build
```

@current_build.task

```
 def package_for_spark(build):
     download_dependency_cmd = ['pip3', 'install',
                           '-r', '.requirements.txt', '-t', 'dist']
     download_dependency_cmd.extend(index_url_paras)
     logger.info('download cmd: {}'.format(download_dependency_cmd))
     print(download_dependency_cmd)
     build.executables.run(download_dependency_cmd)
```